Top Element in Finite Coxeter Groups
I am currently struggling with a seemingly easy proof about Coxeter group elements:

Suppose that $(W,S)$ is a finite Coxeter group. Let $w\in W$ and $J=S\setminus D_L(w)$. 
Show that $x\vee w=w_0 \iff x\geq w_0(J)$.

(Notation: $D_L(w)=\{s\in S$ $|$ $l(sw)<l(w)\}$, $w_0=$ top element of $W$, $w_0(J)=$ top element of the subgroup $W_J$, and $x\vee w$ is the join of $x$ and $w$, i.e. the least upper bound of $\{x,w\}$ in $W$)
Both directions look abstract for me. Could anyone offer me some hint? Thanks.

There are several partial orders on $W$, which one do you use?

This also looks ambiguous to me. So far, the book introduced Bruhat order and weak order (left or right), but it did not specify the order used in the question. But the book usually writes the weak order with subscripts L or R, so I guess it is the Bruhat order.
